# AES MixColumns using L and E lookup tables

Tags: aes, finite-field

I am trying to verify the multiplication by $\mathtt{02}$ in Galois Fields for MixColumns function using the **L** and **E** lookup tables. I could verify $\mathtt{D4}\cdot\mathtt{02}=\mathtt{B3}$ by manual calculation and using the lookup tables. However, I can't verify $\mathtt{87}\cdot\mathtt{02} = \mathtt{15}$ using the lookup table. Using the **L** table, $74 + 19 = 93$. Look up the **E** table for $93$ and it is $\mathtt{3D}$.
Where am i going wrong?

Link to lookup tables: Page 8 of [this document](http://www.infosecwriters.com/text_resources/pdf/AESbyExample.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The values in the tables are listed in hexadecimal; hence the Log table maps $\mathtt{87}$ to $\mathtt{0x74} = 116$.  Similarly, it maps $\mathtt{02}$ to $\mathtt{0x19} = 25$, and $(116 + 25) \bmod 255 = 141 = \mathtt{0x8D}$; looking up $\mathtt{8D}$ in the Exp table gives us... $\mathtt{15}$ (actually, $\mathtt{0x15}$).